# "This is an audit" error popup in an audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, low-quality-posts, popup

Today while I was reviewing Low Quality posts, I got [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/20206834) with a code only answer. So I tried to add a comment to the user saying it's better to add some description. Suddenly an error popup came saying,

> **This is an audit.**

---

[image]

---

Even the post is a good one I don't see any harm which a comment may cause. So blocking comments in audit posts really necessary?

Comment: previously you would fail an audit if you commented on a post that required recommend deletion to pass. That also got lots of users by surprise as they tried to be helpful towards the OP. The *fix* was to reveal you're dealing with an audit if you try to comment. Just copy the text, click the link at the right and post your comment on the real thing. Then pass your audit.

Comment: @rene " click the link at the right" Which link on the right exactly?

Comment: @DavidPostill On the right hand side at the bottom of the column starting with "other answers" is a link just called "link". That one takes you to the real post.

Comment: @rene the previous situation is much worse as I see. That's what I'm trying to say a comment won't harm the post. the audit's final result should be the choices given on top of the post.

Comment: @RoshanaPitigala sure, that is basically a repeat of some earlier [meta complaints](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=audit+fail+comment)

Comment: _So blocking comments in audit posts really necessary?_ - Questions selected as audits might be shown to many reviewers, i.e., audits generate an abnormal amount of attention. The current solution prevents a sudden rise of comments.

Comment: Gah, I deleted the comment. I meant to say that in the situation rene described, the post no longer exists for a comment to be added to.